# DNS Error that Intendly Generated by PHP

Tags: php, dns

I have an domain name that linked to another domain name as an "Addon Domain":

```
example.com
```

But I am also reaching it like that:

```
example.maindomainname.com
```

I dont want it to reached like that, but I cant change server (Apache) setting (but .htaccess), and dont want to generate only "404" error,

To hide/break any relation between "example.com" and "maindomainname.com":
**How to create/generate intendly an "DNS error" or something like that?**

Comment: Depends on what web server you are using. Maybe the best thing would be to use a 301 redirect from the one domain to the other. This way the user always arrives at you preferred url.

Comment: And what does `php` do here?

Comment: you can make a php code to check for the domain name, and if its `example.maindomainname.com` then die with the 404 error. thats the simplest solution i can thing of (without the need for any other thing than php)

Comment: Sorry forget to mention the server; it is an Apache server @Jerodev

Comment: I have an Wordpress installation, and I want PHP to generate an error that looks like DNS error, or something like. So thats brakes any obvious relations between "example.com" and "maindomainname.com"... Does that possible? @u_mulder